# Create new jsp file without annotation

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I don't need any annotation. How can I create jsp file without annotation?
And How to change method `doGet()` and `doPost()` ?
I ask about some kind of initialization.

[[image]]

Comment: Note : the file you posted a screenshot about is a .java file, not jsp

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On Project - > New -> JSP File